# video streaming using vlc player and amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, udp, video-streaming, vlc

I am using vlc and amazonEC2 for video streaming.

After creating instance in amazonEC2, i got below public DNS address

```
ec2-54-251-165-32.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I trying to stream a video from local machine to 5009 **udp** port of above address by the help of udp.

In the vlc streaming wizard i given address as

```
ec2-54-251-165-32.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

udp port as

```
5009
```

Active transcoding as

```
video-H.264+AAC(TS)
```

And selected

```
stream all elementry streams
```

Now i trying to play streaming by using the help of vlc *open network stream* with following address

```
udp://@ec2-54-251-165-32.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5009
```

video not playing, getting following error in vlc log

```
main error: socket bind error (Cannot assign requested address)
access_udp error: cannot open socket
main error: open of `udp://@ec2-54-251-165-32.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5009' failed: (null)
```

When i try same procedure in local network its working properly, correct me where i doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the Security Group for the instance and open up the port 509 for UDP protocol for inbound and outbound traffic.

Refer to the official [AWS Security Group documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#working-with-security-groups) for more details.